# Not able to redirect to client side with token from server(express) side route

Tags: express

I am using 'googleapis' npm package to do token based google authentication.
I am redirected to '/api/auth/success/google' route inside express after google provided authentication and redirects us to the uri stated in google app credentials.

The problem I am facing is that ,I have retrieved the tokens on server side,but I am unable to send those tokens to client side for them to be saved in cookies.

The problem I am facing is because,'/api/auth/success/google' is redirected from google side and not an ajax call from client side.So if I send the tokens back in res,where will it redirect.Also please suggest a way to redirect from server side to client side,along with access_token.

```js
server side code.

//Route reached after google successful login/authentication

app.get('/api/auth/success/google',function(req,res){
  console.log("inside redirect");
  var code = req.query.code;
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if(!err) {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    }
    res.sendFile('./index.html');
  });
})


Client side call

//Google login requested from this function

googleLogin(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : baseURL + 'api/authenticate/google',
      success: (function(data) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            document.location.href = data.redirect;
        }

      }).bind(this)
    });
  } 

//Route handling request of google access

app.post('/api/authenticate/google',function(req,res){

  // generate a url that asks permissions for Google+ and Google Calendar scopes
  var scopes = [
    googlecredentials.SCOPE[0],
    googlecredentials.SCOPE[1]
  ];

  var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline', // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
    scope: scopes // If you only need one scope you can pass it as string
  });
  res.send({ redirect: url });
})

//Google App Credentials

var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(googlecredentials.CLIENT_ID, googlecredentials.CLIENT_SECRET, googlecredentials.REDIRECT_URL);


googlecredentials.CLIENT_ID - 858093863410-j9ma1i7lgapupip1ckegc61plrlledtq.apps.googleusercontent.com

REDIRECT_URL - http://localhost:3000/api/auth/success/google  where localhost:3000 runs server side
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send the redirect URL back in the res, the client-side should be able to check for the presence of the redirect URL in the response, and if it exists, push your user to that URL.